# Draw signature over PDF file

Tags: ios, pdf

I have an app in which some PDF files are downloaded and my problem is simple : I need to have the ability to sign them (drawing signature on screen) anywhere and save it to PDF format without modifying  the structure of my PDF file.

The new feature in iOS 9 : Markup in the mail app does EXACTLY what I need. However, I don't want to use Mail in my app...

I've found on the web some ways to Generate PDF content, but very few examples and nothing that could help me with my problem.

Opening a PDF, turning it into NSData, create a context to render the signature then render both the PDF and the layered signature to finally save the NSData to PDF seems to be a pain, isn't it ?

Can someone help me either

- Use markup features without using mail app or use it as transparent as possible for the user
- Or, any reliable tutorial to draw signature over PDF without using a third-party app ?

Thank you,

Comment: This guide shows how to draw over an existing PDF (using an original as a template) http://b2cloud.com.au/tutorial/drawing-over-a-pdf-in-ios-pdf-template/

Comment: Thanks @SomeGuy, I've been trying his solution however I don't know what I'm supposed to do when he says "do something with data". I believe data represents the edited PDF and need to be-re-saved as a PDF ? Then I would need to use a UIWebView to render it ? Moreover this tutorial shows you how to add stuff without seeing it, I absolutely need so add the signature at the exact place my user decided to (need to render PDF before)

Comment: @H4Hugo your problem solved or not??

Comment: @GajendraKChauhan negative, that was a long time ago